# Flask-restful API not accepting json

Tags: python, rest, api, flask-restful

I am trying to learn how to do apis. I copied everything from the book exactly but i am unable to post to the api.  I tried posting `{'name':'holy'}` as raw data in `postman`( an json posting tool) to api and I get the vladation help message error"No Name provided":but when i try `name=holy` it works fine. I thought it was not suppose to work like that, How do i get it to work with `{'name':'holy'}`

```
from flask import Flask, request,render_template, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api,marshal_with, fields, reqparse

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


class UserApi(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser()
        self.reqparse.add_argument(
            'name',
            required=True,
            help='No name provided',
            location=['form', 'json']
        )

    def get(self):
        return jsonify ({"first_name":"Holy","last_name": "Johnson"})

    def post(self):
        args = self.reqparse.parse_args()
        return jsonify ({"first_name":"Holy","last_name": "Johnson"})



api.add_resource(UserApi, '/users')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code should work - you have to specify the request header `Content-Type: application/json`. The reason why is because `flask-restful`'s `reqparse` module tries to parse [its data from `flask.request.json`](http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/reqparse.html#argument-locations), which is only set if `Content-Type: application/json` is set.

If you have access to `curl` (or `wget`), you can do the following to test:

```
$shell> curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name": "holly"}' http://localhost:5000/users
{
  "first_name": "Holy",
  "last_name": "Johnson"
}
```

In Postman, you can set a header, like shown in the screenshot below. [image]